# Segmentation fault when initializing array

Tags: python, segmentation-fault, rfid

I am getting a segmentation fault when initializing an array.

I have a callback function from when an RFID tag gets read

```
IDS = []
def readTag(e):
    epc = str(e.epc, 'utf-8')
    if not epc in IDS:
        now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
        IDS.append([epc, now, "name.instrument"])
```

and a main function from which it's called

```
def main():
    for x in vals:
        IDS.append([vals[0], vals[1], vals[2]])
    for x in IDS:
        print(x[0])
    r = mercury.Reader("tmr:///dev/ttyUSB0", baudrate=9600)
    r.set_region("NA")

    r.start_reading(readTag, on_time=1500)
    input("press any key to stop reading: ")
    r.stop_reading()
```

The error occurs because of the line `IDS.append([epc, now, "name.instrument"])`. I know because when I replace it with a print call instead the program will run just fine. I've tried using different types for the array objects (integers), creating an array of the same objects outside of the append function, etc. For some reason just creating an array inside the "readTag" function causes the segmentation fault like `row = [1,2,3]`

Does anyone know what causes this error and how I can fix it? Also just to be a little more specific, the readTag function will work fine for the first two (only ever two) calls, but then it crashes and the Reader object that has the start_reading() function is from the mercury-api

Comment: Side note: you seem to have lists, not arrays. There are arrays in python but `['this']` is a list.

Comment: `if not epc in IDS:` will never be satisfied as currently it's nested in another list. You want to re-check your steps and be sure you what is the better data structure to use here.

Comment: Also later only lists would be appended to `IDS`, so the list `epc` will never be `in IDS`.

Comment: @OluwafemiSule good catch. I seem to have overlooked that when I was debugging the code for the segmentation fault. Thank you!

Comment: @AndrasDeak New to python. I appreciate the explanation! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extend Michael's answer, this appears to be an issue with scoping and the API you're using. In general pure-Python doesn't seg-fault. Or at least, it *shouldn't* seg-fault unless there's a bug in the interpreter, or some extension that you're using. That's not to say pure-Python won't break, it's just that a genuine seg-fault indicates the problem is probably the result of something messy outside of your code.

I'm assuming you're using [this Python API](https://github.com/gotthardp/python-mercuryapi).

In that case, the README.md mentions that the `Reader.start_reader()` method you're using is "asynchronous". Meaning it invokes a new thread or process and returns immediately and then the background thread continues to call your callback each time something is scanned.

I don't really know enough about the nitty gritty of CPython to say exactly what going on, but you've declared `IDS = []` as a global variable and it seems like the background thread is running the callback with a different context to the main program. So when it attempts to access `IDS` it's reading memory it doesn't own, hence the seg-fault.

Because of how restrictive the callback is and the apparent lack of a buffer, this might be an oversight on the behalf of the developer. If you really need asynchronous reads it's worth sending them an issue report.

Otherwise, considering you're just waiting for input you probably don't need the asynchronous reads, and you could use the synchronous `Reader.read()` method inside your own busy loop instead with something like:

```
try:
    while True:
        readTags(r.read(timeout=10))
except KeyboardInterrupt: ## break loop on SIGINT (Ctrl-C)
    pass
```

Note that `r.read()` returns a list of tags rather than just one, so you'd need to modify your callback slightly, and if you're writing more than just a quick script you probably want to use threads to interrupt the loop properly as SIGINT is pretty hacky.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a scoping issue to me; the mercury library doesn't have permission to access your list's memory address, so when it invokes your callback function `readTag(e)` a segfault occurs. I don't think that the behavior that you want is supported by that library

Comment: This statement seems really surprising to me, but I don't know anything about mercury. Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: I don't know anything about mercury, but the behavior here is clearly the result of some underlying library (possibly written in C or Java) calling the user-provided callback function and being unable to access the global-scope object provided by the user. That was proven by the fact that it's a segfault that goes away when the OP comments out the line where that list is accessed.